# comparing actual IP with partial IP in PHP

Tags: php, string, ip-address, substring

Using PHP I'd like to compare an actual ip address to part of one, and see if it matches.
For example I want to see if the address matches 12.34.*.*

```
<?php
$rem_address = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$temp = substr ($rem_address,0,6)
if ($temp == "12.34.") echo "It's a match";
?>
```

Is there an easier/better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function **strpos(*$haystack*, *$needle*)** will tell you the first position in the *$haystack* string where the substring appears.

As long as you are careful to check the with the === comparison operator, you can see if `"12.34"` appears at the beginning of the IP address.

```
if (strpos ($rem_address, "12.34.") === 0) echo "It's a match";
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and pay careful attention to the Warning.

Comment: Good solution, but I would add a dot after 34. ;-) Just to be sure of course... since IPv4 segments shouldn't exceed 255.

Comment: Excellent suggestion!  I've fixed that.  (I should have been more careful about copying the original test string.)

Comment: Assuming (as is the case here, but might not always be) that the fragment you're matching is always going to be the same, you COULD do `FOO.BAR` as long as BAR is 26 or higher. If it's <=25 you might run into false positives when you match 12.244 with 12.24. On the other hand you'll never run into 12.345. Still probably safest to do 6 characters in case someone else is modifying the code later, or the IPs change.

Answer (score 2):

```
$parts = explode(".",$rem_address);
if ($parts[0] == "12" && $parts[1] == "34") echo "match";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$full_address = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$pattern = "/^" . preg_quote('12.34') . "/";
$count = preg_match($pattern, $full_address);
if ($count!=0) {
//match
}
?>
```

Comment: Why change `getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');` to `getenv['REMOTE_ADDR'];` Do the () do something different then the []?

Comment: My mistake, no reason to change it. In fact it would not work. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Yet more methods, based on [`ip2long`](http://php.net/ip2long):

```
(ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & 0xFFFF0000) == 0x0C220000
! ((ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & 0xFFFF0000) ^ 0x0C220000)
! ((ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ^ 0x0C220000) >> 16)
```